# How should i search through a string for a sequence of characters such as "x*y"?

Tags: c#, string, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to make a determinat calculator using mathematical Cramer's theorem, as you can see I translated the theorem into code `convertedString = Convert.ToString (x * y1 * 1 + x1 * y2 * 1 + x2 * x * y - (1 * y1 * x2 + 1 * y2 * y + 1 * y * x1));`All good until I am at the point where I need to compute 2 unknown numbers, I don't know how to "tell" in code to the computer that `x + x = 2x` or `3y-y = 2y`, so I tought that if I convert the Crammer's equation into a string I can find all the matches like `x + x` or `y + 2y` or `y * y` and begin from that a solution that can solve my initial problem, like if I find an `x * x` pattern I will  tell the pc through an if statement or something that the pattern `x * x` is `x^2`.
   So that being said, I want to find out the number of specific sequences like `X * y` or `y + x` that are present in a string, I did try some `foreach` loops and `for` loops but I can't get it to work and I don't know how should I approach the problem next, plase help.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using InputMath;

namespace MathWizard
{
     class Determinants
    {
        //Determinant of a first point and a second graphical point on the xoy axis.
         public static void BasicDeterminant()
        {
            float x;
            float y;
            float x1 = Input.x1;
            float y1 = Input.y1;
            float x2 = Input.x2;
            float y2 = Input.y2;
            float result;
            string convertedString;
            string pointsValue;
            string[] point;

            Console.WriteLine("Please introduce the 2 graphical points ( A and B) \n in the order x1 y1 x2 y2, separated by a space ");

            pointsValue = Console.ReadLine();
            point = pointsValue.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


            x1 = Convert.ToInt32(point[0]);
            y1 = Convert.ToInt32(point[1]);
            x2 = Convert.ToInt32(point[2]);
            y2 = Convert.ToInt32(point[3]);


            //The Cramer's Rule for solving a 2 points determinant ( P1(x1,y1) and P2(x2,y2)
            convertedString = Convert.ToString (x * y1 * 1 + x1 * y2 * 1 + x2 * x * y - (1 * y1 * x2 + 1 * y2 * y + 1 * y * x1));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You declare `x1, x2, y1, y2` as `float`s, but then use `Convert.ToInt16` to get them from the input. Which is the correct type?

Comment: This code contains nothing about finding strings. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Did you copy/paste someone else's code and then try to modify it? It makes no sense. 'x' and 'y' are always '1', and you have some hard-coded '1''s in there as well, all used for multiplication..??

Answer (score 0):

```
 bool found = false;
 int xyCount = 0;

 if(convertedString.Contains("X*Y")){
     found = true;
      xyCount++;
      //makes a substring without the first case of the "X*Y"
      string s = convertedString.SubString(convertedString.IndexOf("X*Y"))
       if(s.Contains("X*Y")){
         xyCount++;
     }
```

Its probably not the best way to do it, but you can probably make a better method doing something like this

Comment: Can I use this solution to find EVERY pattern from the string? even if it is the same? Thank you for your answer tho :).

Comment: This will only  find it once, to find it more than once, you will have to use .indexof. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following `regex` which will find x*y with case insensitivity for each operator:

```
string pattern = /(x(\*|\+|\-|\/|\^)y)/gi;
```

then you could do some `string.Contains(pattern);` to check.  Let me know if this helps.

**Edit: Updated Pattern**

Updated the pattern so that it will also allow variables such as `y9` or `X10`.  Any single  character (x or y) followed by any amount of numbers.

```
string pattern =/(x\d*(\*|\+|\-|\/|\^)y\d*)/gi; // could match X1*y9
```

This doesn't account for whitespaces so you could use some `.replace()` to get rid of whitespace or use `.split(/\s/)` and get a string array without whitespace before using this pattern.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of your solution into my cod, I don't understand how should I implement it...Thank you!

Comment: Well there is still confusion for me.  I'm not sure as to why your variables start as `floats`, then get converted to `int`, then you convert it all `toString()`.  When I first had read this, it only asked to find any sequence `x*Y` for example. Now you want your code to add unknowns? @Noobie